# Show Extension Builder absent in Develop menu in Safari 13

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extensions, catalina

I am trying to re-add several extensions to Safari 13 that "are no longer supported," by adding them back via "Show Extension Builder" in the Develop menu.  But that is no longer in the Develop menu!

Is there another way to return my older extensions like Amazon Assistant, Amazon Wish List, WOT etc., to Safari 13?

Comment: The old style extensions built with Safari Extension Builder are not supported in Safari 13, you'll need to look for updated versions.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/370871/347564. Can you please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Removed support for Legacy Safari Extensions.

<sup>from [Safari 13 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari_release_notes/safari_13_release_notes)</sup>

which I interpret as no support for developing legacy ones either. How would you develop an extension which you can't even run/test on the browser?

You might need to [build a new one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/building_a_safari_app_extension)  or [convert the older one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/converting_a_legacy_safari_extension_to_a_safari_app_extension).

Comment: You can [convert your old extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/converting_a_legacy_safari_extension_to_a_safari_app_extension), or [build a new one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/building_a_safari_app_extension).

Comment: @red_menace I meant no support for developing legacy ones. Ofc newer ones will continue to be made.

Comment: Thank you, Ankii and red_menace, for your answers. There is an easier way to convert legacy extensions, via this article from OS X Daily, "How to Bypass “Safari no longer supports unsafe extension” Error in Mac OS Mojave."  For this to work, I need to find, in the Develop menu, "Show Extension Builder," which is NOT THERE in the new update, Safari 13!  If it were, I could add the (converted) .zip file and run it in Safari, and it would stay in my Extensions file in the Preference pane.  I would attach the pdf of the article, but I don't know how to on this site.   mtgraffeo

Comment: @mtgraffeo yes I know that method, I just suggested that to David today in [this answer about omnikey](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370465/omnikey-for-safari-13/370520#370520). Just put the link of the article if you wanted to but title is enough to search for. I just answered you question "Is there a way to get extensions?".... "Show extension builder has been removed" was just a statement we cannot do much about.

Comment: Thanks again, ankii.  That article is very similar to the one I read.  So, no more WOT, Amazon Assistant, etc., unless I hear back from those developers or if I can find a way to DOWNGRADE to the previous Safari!   mtgraffeo