# How to upgrade macOS minor update without updating Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, mojave, upgrade

I want to upgrade to  macOS 10.14.6 from 10.14.5 but keep Safari 12.1.1 intact instead of Safari 13, which I guess comes with it.

Is there a way to upgrade macOS, but not Safari?

macOS Mojave (obviously), MacBook Air 2017.

[image]

Clicking the top "More Info..." takes me to macOS Catalina webpage.

Clicking the second "More Info" opens the tray below.

[image]

Comment: I think it'll most likely get closed as dupe of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372670/safari-from-macos-catalina-not-working-on-macos-mojave?rq=1#comment500232_372670 where I myself commented.

Comment: Don't think it is.a duplicate as you haven't updated yet and so don't have the mentioned incompatible files.  If you have *only* "Check for updates" selected on *System Preferences* > *Software Update* > *Advanced* then when you check for updates and 10.14.6 is offered then on [More Info...](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201541) you should see the OS update and Safari update separately and you can uncheck the Safari one.  Do you see anything like that there?

Comment: @lx07 I remember seeing it, but when Catalina came out, I can no longer find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am already on 10.14.6 so can't confirm this but have downloaded [10.14.6 Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2011?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) (I didn't check the Combo Update) and looking the `.pkg` with [Suspicious Package](https://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/) shows it includes Safari version 12 not version 13.  Note it is 12.1.2 not 12.1.1 as you now have.

[image: Suspicious Package 10.14.6]

[Mojave 10.14.6 Supplemental Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2015?locale=en_US) also contains Safari 12.1.2.

[image: Suspicious Package Supplemental]

It isn't clear why you aren't offered Safari 13 through *Software Update*.  The [Safari 13 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari_release_notes/safari_13_release_notes) say 10.14.5:

> Safari 13 ships with iOS 13 and macOS 10.15. It’s also available for macOS 10.14.5 and 10.13.6.

I seem to remember being offered the Safari update at the same time as 10.14.6 but it may have been a supplemental update or perhaps it changed.

In any case it appears Safari 13 isn't in the updater packages so you should be safe updating that way.

The Safari Package appears later.

[image: Safari 13 package]

Comment: I saw it now, so added the image. Thanks for saving me from all the ads : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370551/show-extension-builder-absent-in-develop-menu-in-safari-13/370568#370568  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373375/how-to-run-an-applescript-when-safari-starts-up