# Tab Stack like unsupported burkeware

Tags: applescript, safari, tabs

I was wondering if there is a script I can add to Safari 13.0.1 to make the active tab move to the left.  The description of what I am trying to do is here; https://blog.burkeware.com/2015/12/01/tab-stack-for-safari/
I clicked the link and then downloaded. When I clicked the extension to install, the box popped up that says my version of safari doesn't support this.

Is there some script out there I could get this action accomplished, and what are the steps to get that script installed?  I have used some script before, but only with Automator.

Maybe someone out there could update the old Tab Stack to work with new Safari.

Hopefully someone can help, thanks 
Cap'n

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370465/omnikey-for-safari-13/370520#370520

Comment: https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/install-any-safari-extension-macos-mojave/