# Omnikey for Catalina and Safari 13

Tags: macos, safari, catalina, safari-extensions

Omnikey is a very useful extension, allowing user-customizable URL-bar searching for Safari up through v.12.

Safari now nags for update to v.13. As [I found previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370465/omnikey-for-safari-13), Omnikey doesn't work with Safari 13, or at least doesn't do so without some fussing.

I assume (but don't know) that Safari 13 is a mandatory inclusion when one upgrades to Catalina. Has anyone tried Omnikey on Catalina running Safari v.13? Do any of the workarounds discussed in my prior question allow Omnikey to function on macOS Catalina as before?