# com.automator.runner.xpc is not allowed to send keystrokes

Tags: keyboard, applescript, automator

I have two MacBooks. Both run the same MacOS version. I installed the same Automator script in both.
But on the older MacBook I get:

> The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “System Events got an error: com.automator.runner.xpc is not allowed to send keystrokes.”

I added Automator to the Security -> Accessibility section in both. It even works on the older one. But then it suddenly stops. It just don't get why...

Comment: What version of **macOS**?

Comment: Most recent one.

Comment: Does **System Events** have **Accessibility** privileges?

Comment: yeah it has these privileges.

Comment: You should paste the script so we can test it out. I usually change the syntax or isolate the problem to see if it works alone. Often it is just a matter of tweaking the "delay" between commands. Older computers need more time to get ready for the next step.

Answer (score 18):

I have solved this issue recently in case anyone is interested in how. It is NOT actually necessary for **System Events** to have direct **Accessibility** privileges. What you need to add are a total of 3 apps, **Automator**, **Script Editor**, and **AppleScript Utility**.

The **Automator** and **Script Editor** apps are found within the `~/Applications` and `~/Applications/Utilities` folders, respectively. What is harder to find is the **AppleScript Utility** app, seen below:

[image]

To add **AppleScript Utility** app, click the `+` button on **Accessibility**, then navigate to (a shortcut is `CMD+SHIFT+G`)

```
/System/Library/CoreServices
```

then `open` the application called `AppleScript Utility`.

Afterwards, run a script in automator again, which updates the privileges and things should run well after. In summary, **Automator**, **Script Editor**, and **AppleScript Utility** need to be added to **Accessibility**.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for me. Actually I found out whatever I add to accessibility makes it work. But only to restart at max. Then it just stops working again. Usually does after a few minutes.

Comment: Ugh I'm having the same problem. When I first followed these instructions, it worked, but restarting broke it again.

Comment: Ok, I found another solution! SCRIPTS CANNOT HAVE SPACES IN THEIR NAMES! Replaces spaces with dashes/underscores fixed my situation, along with following all the advice above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036828/209859

Answer (score 11):

I found that all applications involved that are targeted by the Automation also need to be given Accessibility permission.  So, if your Automation reloads a page in Chrome then both Chrome and Automator require Accessibility permissions.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I use a workflow to pass search queries to different websites in Safari (see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/371138/214359). Giving Accessibility access to Safari did the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately also does not work for me.

Comment: After doing adding Automator, Script Editor, and AppleScript Utility to Accessibility as user321627 noted, it worked fine...for a few minutes. Later in the day, it did not work. How quirky? As you suggested and add the target application to have accessibility permissions and then my automation worked. Grr, apple!

Comment: I have found the same - that the target application needs to be given Accessibility permission. However I found that Automator actually doesn't need Accessibility permission if the target application has it. I end up temporarily granting permission to the target application while I'm invoking the Automator script and then revoking it.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that **COULD** be causing problems is spaces in the script name. I have no idea why, but as [this comment on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973241/applescript-application-is-not-allowed-to-send-keystrokes/59036828#59036828) pointed out, it seems that having spaces in the filename of the script can cause these errors to persist even if you've added everything possible to the Acessibility app whitelist!

### So remove all spaces from your script filename and replace with `-` or `_`!

Then go back through the many useful answers in this thread and make sure you've whitelisted all the apps needed.

Worked for me, hopefully this helps some others who are trapped in error-hell!

Comment: I don't think that is the problem but it is a good policy just to do this to avoid errors in general.