# Automator script to paste each word on clipboard followed by tab key

Tags: keyboard, automator, copy-paste

The contents of my clipboard are a series of 10 words separated by spaces. I would like to paste them into an application which requires each word to be entered individually into text boxes, where you can navigate to the next text box by pressing the Tab key.

How can I create an Automator script to split the contents of my clipboard on space, and then paste each word followed by the tab key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create an Automator script to split the contents of my clipboard on space, and then paste each word followed by the tab key?

You can use a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator** *workflow* to accomplish this.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set cbText to (the clipboard)

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
set cbTextAsList to text items of cbText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}

repeat with aWord in cbTextAsList
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke aWord
        delay 0.05
        key code 48 --  # Tab key
        delay 0.05
    end tell
end repeat
```

---

**Notes:**

- The *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina**.
- Whatever the *words* are to be typed into must be *frontmost* as this is required for **UI Scripting** *code*, which is what **System Events** is doing.
- As coded, it assume focus is already in the first *text box* the *first word* is to be typed when the *script* is triggered.

---

If you really want to paste the *words* instead of typing, then use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* instead:

```applescript
set cbText to (the clipboard)

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
set cbTextAsList to text items of cbText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}

repeat with aWord in cbTextAsList
    set the clipboard to ""
    delay 0.05
    set the clipboard to aWord
    delay 0.05
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "v" using command down
        delay 0.05
        key code 48 --  # Tab key
        delay 0.05
    end tell
end repeat
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, it works very well. One small issue is with permissions, as described here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/405338/91027 with workarounds

Comment: Potential pitfall: `if contents of aWord ≠ (last item of cbTextAsList)` in situations where `aword` ***does*** equal the last item in the list, but is not itself the last item in the list. I think a counter variable needs to be used to construct the loop.

Comment: @CJK, Yeah, I agree and will update it in the morning... off to sleep. Thanks.

Comment: @mark, I've removed the `if` _statement_ as it could be problematic as mentioned by CJK's comment. If you do not want _tab_ pressed after the last _word_, let me know and I add some _conditional coding_, otherwise I'll let it stand as it now is, thanks.